# How to not show the Navigator Bar in android when scroll up

Tags: android, lockscreen, homescreen

I am working on a android Lock Screen project,It working on full screen flawless,however when user scroll up from bottom ,3 button from navigator bar show up,how can I disable this,I googled and see this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fotoable.locker&hl=en when scroll up this app bring that own bar,how can I achieve this ?
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem,add these Flags and the problem solve

```
    v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```